# Mostrar texto dentro de un input

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber como puedo insertar texto en una caja input de tipo texto, mi funcion es esta:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("btn_calcular").onclick = function () {
    //tomamos el valor de los nombres de los puentes
    let nombre_puentes = document.getElementById('nombres_puentes').value
    //separamos los nombres de los puentes
    nombre_puentes = nombre_puentes.split(",")
    //tomamos el valor de las longitudes de los puentes
    let longitud_puentes = document.getElementById("longitud_puente").value
    //separamos las longitudes
    longitud_puentes = longitud_puentes.split(",")


    //convertimos en flotantes el valor de las longitudes de los puentes para que no se concatene
    for (var i = 0; i < longitud_puentes.length; i++) {
      longitud_puentes[i] = parseFloat(longitud_puentes[i])
    }
    //multiplicamos el precio por cada metro de puente
    let resultado = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < longitud_puentes.length; i++) {
      //convertimos en flotantes los vaores
      longitud_puentes[i] *= 300
      resultado += longitud_puentes[i]
    }
 }
```

Comment: Lo que quieres setear como valor del input text es el resultado de esa función? es decir, la variable "resultado"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < longitud_puentes.length; i++) {
  resultado = resultado.concat(`${nombre_puentes}:${longitud_puentes[i]} <br>`)
}
```

Saludos, pon tú código entero y luego selecciónalo todo y en las herramientas de ayuda, el 5º iconito **{}** úsalo.

Para cambiar el valor de un **input**:

```
document.getElementById("longitud_puente").value = nuevovalor;
```

El **ID** debe ser único.